# I/O Systems, calculate period register and a prescale value

Tags: io, embedded

the question is:

> Consider a 16-bit timer that has seven prescaling options: 1:64, 1:32,
> 1:16, 1:8, 1:4, 1:2, 1:1. The timer is clocked at a frequency of 50
> Mhz. Assume further that the timer is configured to trigger an
> interrupt. Decide on a value for the period register and a prescale
> value such that the interrupt is triggered every 20 ms.

And my answer is: period register value 125000 and prescale value 1:8

The peruid register value was correct but the prescale value they said:

> "The period value does not fit in the period register".

What dose that mean and how can I see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your quote: `... a 16-bit timer ...`
Obviously a 16-bit register can't hold a value of 125000.

You need at least a prescaler of 1:16

Math:

```
period * (freq / prescaler) = timer-value
```

You have to choose the prescaler value from the possible values so that the timer-value is in the 16-bit range

Comment: okej so max value for 16-bit register is 65535? I did not think about that, that makes sense. thank you